# Does Comodo Antivirus support Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, antivirus

Does Comodo Antivirus for Linux work with 14.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does.  I downloaded the 32bit .deb file, and used Gdebi ti install.  If you don't have Gdebi installed, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

[image]

Comment: What is Gdebi? Can i just install it without Gdebi?

Comment: Yes you can, just do `sudo dpkg -i <file_name>.deb`.

Comment: Also if i were to use Gdebi how would I do it

Comment: Just right click the file, and open with Gdebi.

Comment: After installation it says I need to enter something into the terminal

Comment: It says file system filter driver not loaded

Comment: See [Here](http://forums.comodo.com/comodo-antivirus-for-linux-cavl/ubuntu-1204-comodo-filesystem-filter-driver-t101570.0.html).  Download the file [Here](http://http://www.bondoffamily-net.com/~kinta-chan/techknow/Linux/RedirFS/src/driver.tar).  Also take a look at [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2221371).

Comment: Can i still use it without file system filter driver?

Comment: I have been using it for about 2 months, and it works.

Answer (score 1):

There is simple soution:

1) You can get this driver "redirfs,avflt,dazuko -- kernel 3.18 or lower" needed from here:

http://www.bondoffamily-net.com/~kinta-chan/techknow/DownLoad/DownLoad.html

2) Go to folder where you downloaded the driver:

`sudo mv driver.tar /opt/COMODO/driver.tar`

3) Then change directory

`cd /opt/COMODO`

4) Install it 
`sudo ./post_setup.sh`
(**Please be carefull** at end of licence you NEED to accept with `Y` and then you can add email address, and choose Language `8`)

5) Restart cmdavd
`/etc/init.d/cmdavd restart`

6) Reboot if must

7) RIGHT CLICK on System Tray icon and click

1. Antivirus Security Level
2. On Access

DONE!!!